# How activate Wifi in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I just installed windows 8.1 and I can not turn on wifi, previously had windows 7, and turned on and off by a combination of keyboard, but now will not let me activate, because I was disabled when you reinstall.

Comment: did u updated wifi driver?by default u could find wifi settings on setting menu or press win+q and type wifi on

Comment: yes, i update wifi driver, but nothin :(

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. You haven't told us much about the computer. There isn't enough information here to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the function key installed on your system. If it is a new laptop, there should be some software dedicated to operation of the laptop's function keys. You can search for it on the manufacturer's website.